# Mongo aggregate with objects in array to match to other document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections

Incident

```
{ 
     _id:...,
     suspects : [{id:...,...},{}...]
}
```

and 
Suspect

```
{
    _id:...
}
```

The suspects in the Incident document are nested object that is not the equal to the document in collection Suspects but a subset with an id that matches the suspect in the suspects collection.

I would like to query the db, either for the incidents and to attach at the array (or create new one) with the actual documents that matches the ids
or 
Query for suspects with attached a property that is the incident document where the suspect id exists in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `id` field in the `Incident` collection, and that is corresponding to the actual document `id` in the `Suspect` collection, you can use the `lookup` operator

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

I've setup a sample code in this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qk-mVWTmI-3). Let me know if you need further explanation :)

Comment: Thanks that really helpfull.
I think my current problem is that the id in the suspects is a string and the _id is ObjectId

Comment: In that case you should do the following:
- unwind the suspects array [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- use the combination of `toObjectId` and `addFields` to add a virtual field to your model containing the object id version of your stored id [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/]()
- use the lookup aggregation, using the virtual field from previous step as local field
- group results by incident id

Comment: Here is the `group` operator documentation [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)